# I'm trying to run a Tukey's Test after an ANOVA in R. I keep getting an error message. How should I fix this?

Tags: r, statistics, anova, tukey

I have run an ANOVA in R with distance as my dependent variable, and sleep_category (3 levels) as my independent variable. The ANOVA shows a significant differences between my groups for this measurement, so I want to run a Tukey's test to determine where the difference is.

I ran:

```
dput(sleep_category)
```

the output is:

> c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1)

My code for the ANOVA was:

```
res.aov_distance <- aov(distance ~ sleep_category, data = sleep_analysis)
```

Which gives me this output:

```
summary(res.aov_distance)

Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
sleep_category   1    177  177.09    21.2 5.62e-06 ***
Residuals      387   3233    8.35
```

This is my code for the Tukey's Test, but I am getting an error message:

```
TukeyHSD.aov(res.aov_distance)

Error in TukeyHSD.aov(res.aov_distance) : no factors in the fitted model
In addition: Warning message: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) 
:non-factors ignored: sleep_category
```

It says there are no factors in the model, but the factor sleep_category is in the ANOVA. So I'm not sure what needs to be adjusted. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(sleep_category)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(sleep_category, 20))`.

Comment: Does `class(sleep_category)` return `factor` ?

Comment: George Dontas, no, it's numerical. I bet that's the issue. Can you remind me which function to use to change from numerical to function? Thank you so much!

Comment: Rui, I have done so above now. Do you think George's idea is what was wrong? I appreciate your comment.

Comment: `sleep_category <- as.factor(sleep_category)`
You can find more by googling, i.e. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Hik030y5Ns